# Python Dictionary key-value relationship terminology

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am teaching a basic Python to some students and this simple question came to my mind. While teaching about Python dictionaries, I could no longer consistently read the contents (key : value) of a given dictionary properly aloud. At one time I said **"1 (key) is to red (value)"** etc and at other times I said **"1 maps to red"** and so on. I am wondering if there is a uniformly accepted term in Python for the relationship between keys and values in a dictionary.

Comment: `1 points to red`?

Comment: I think all these make sense. But is there a uniform "Pythonic" way to say it?

Comment: So you are looking for the term that is used when discussing a dictionaries relationship between the `key` and the `value` ?

Comment: This would hardly be a Python-only problem, and subject to cultural biases.

Comment: "maps to" is always the language I've found most consistent and accurate.

Comment: @InbarRose: Yes. As an analogy, consider `a|b` in maths. Everybody would say `a divides b`. I couldn't find anything similar for key, value pair for python dictionary.

Comment: There is no "Pythonic" way to speak about a data structure. An association between elements should generally be understood by anyone who knows what a map/dictionary/associative array is

Comment: @cricket_007 : Sure. My students also do understand the relationship. But when it comes to explaining it to others, they (as well as me!) get confused as how to say it.

Comment: There is no one way to describe a dictionary. You could list all key-value pairs, or you could say the pair (X, Y) exists, or you could say the value Y exists for both keys X and  Z... It really depends what you are trying to describe

Comment: on [python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) it is phrased as `value stored in key`, so `red (is) stored in 1`